# pandas dataframe conditional population of a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, fillna

I am working on manipulation of a column(Trend) in pandas DataFrame. Below is my source DataFrame. Currently I have set it to 0.

[image]

The logic I want to use to populate Trend column is below

1. if df['Close'] > df.shift(1)['Down'] then 1
2. if df['Close'] < df.shift(1)['Up'] then -1
3. if any one of the above condition does not meet then, df.shift(1)['Trend']. if this value is NaN then set it to 1.

Above code in plainText,

1. if current close is greater then previous row value of **Down** column then 1
2. if current close is less than previous row value of **Up** column then -1
3. if any one of those conditions does not meet, then set previous row value of **Trend** column as long as its **not NaN**. if its NaN then set to  1

**UPDATE**

Data as text

```
   Close        Up      Down  Trend
   3.138       NaN       NaN      0
   3.141       NaN       NaN      0
   3.141       NaN       NaN      0
   3.130       NaN       NaN      0
   3.110       NaN       NaN      0
   3.130  3.026432  3.214568      0
   3.142  3.044721  3.214568      0
   3.140  3.047010  3.214568      0
   3.146  3.059807  3.214568      0
   3.153  3.064479  3.214568      0
   3.173  3.080040  3.214568      0
   3.145  3.080040  3.214568      0
   3.132  3.080040  3.214568      0
   3.131  3.080040  3.209850      0
   3.141  3.080040  3.209850      0
   3.098  3.080040  3.205953      0
   3.070  3.080040  3.195226      0
```

**Expected output**

[image]

Comment: What is your expected output from these data?

Comment: could you also provide a bit more representative sample? If you look at the current dataset, none of the conditions are satisfied, so it'll all be nan

Comment: @enke - just to clarify your point "it'all be nan" -- if its nan, then set to 1 as per third logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `numpy.select` to select values depending on which condition is satisfied. Then pass the outcome of `numpy.select` to `fillna` to fill in missing "Trend" values with it (this is used to not lose existing "Trend" values). Then since NaN trend values must be filled with previous "Trend" value, we use `ffill` and fill the remaining NaN values with 1.

```
import numpy as np
df['Trend'] = (df['Trend'].replace(0, np.nan)
               .fillna(pd.Series(np.select([df['Close'] > df['Down'].shift(), 
                                            df['Close'] < df['Up'].shift()],
                                           [1, -1], np.nan), index=df.index))
               .ffill().fillna(1))
```

Output:

```
    Close        Up      Down  Trend
0   3.138       NaN       NaN    1.0
1   3.141       NaN       NaN    1.0
2   3.141       NaN       NaN    1.0
3   3.130       NaN       NaN    1.0
4   3.110       NaN       NaN    1.0
5   3.130  3.026432  3.214568    1.0
6   3.142  3.044721  3.214568    1.0
7   3.140  3.047010  3.214568    1.0
8   3.146  3.059807  3.214568    1.0
9   3.153  3.064479  3.214568    1.0
10  3.173  3.080040  3.214568    1.0
11  3.145  3.080040  3.214568    1.0
12  3.132  3.080040  3.214568    1.0
13  3.131  3.080040  3.209850    1.0
14  3.141  3.080040  3.209850    1.0
15  3.098  3.080040  3.205953    1.0
16  3.070  3.080040  3.195226   -1.0
```